# Why does the message dialog box go behind the Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

Im creating an application with netbeans in Java. When i print a dialog box, it goes behind the Jframe.. I have to drag the frame aside and then click okay.

Comment: You're likely not setting the dialog's parent properly -- check, is it null? It should be the JFrame that launches it.

Comment: Yes it is null.

Comment: Well, then there you go.

Comment: In the future, please show pertinent code so we don't have to make wild guesses.

Comment: My code is: JoptionPane. Showmessagediaglog(null, "message") ;

Comment: Please show code in the question, not in comments. Not necessary now since you know the cause of the problem and its solution, but for future reference. Also it will help for you to go through the How-To-Ask sections of the [help]. Good luck.